# Issue while migrating to Ropsten network

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment, migration

I am trying to migrate the contract to ROPSTEN network. It fails for the following reason. Please advice.

**migrate command**

```
$env:MNEMONIC=' XX XX XX';truffle migrate --reset --network ropsten
```

**Error**

```
Error: There was a timeout while attempting to connect to the network at undefined.
   Check to see that your provider is valid.
   If you have a slow internet connection, try configuring a longer timeout in your Truffle config. Use the networks[networkName].networkCheckTimeout property to do this.
at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\skmsu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\provider\index.js:57:1)
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
```

**truffle-config.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider'); 

console.log('ab - from powershell file process.env.MNEMONIC : '+     
 process.env.MNEMONIC);

const infuraProvider = network => providerWithMnemonic( 
process.env.MNEMONIC || '',
`https://${network}.infura.io/${process.env.INFURA_API_KEY}`
);
const providerWithMnemonic = (mnemonic, rpcEndpoint) =>
new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, rpcEndpoint);

module.exports = {

  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // to customize your Truffle configuration!

  networks: {

development: {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 8545,
  network_id: '*', // eslint-disable-line camelcase
} , 

mainnet: {
  provider: infuraProvider('mainnet'), 
  gasPrice: 10000000000,  // 10 Gwei
  gas: 4000000,
  network_id: '1'
}, 
ropsten: { 
  provider: infuraProvider('ropsten'), 
  gasPrice: 1000000000,  // 1 Gwei
  gas: 4000000,
  network_id: '3' 
} 
  },

  solc: {
optimizer: {
  enabled: true,
  runs: 200
}
  } 

};
```

Comment: Add the command you use to migrate please

Comment: And about infuraProvider(‘ropsten’) , is ‘ropsten’ a placeholder for the url and api key?

Comment: I have updated the question with migrate command.  I use mnemonic seed words in the migrate command. I have also tried the similar for migrating it to ganache development setup. it works fine. but not in ropsten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `@truffle/hdwallet-provider`. `truffle-hdwallet-provider` deprecated.

Also, verify your Ropsten Project ENDPOINT.
`i.e: https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/j4hg5g45jhfj8hgfhfghgtg`

let me know if this works for you, if not then will find some other ways.

Comment: I have the hdwallet-provider installed perfectly.

Comment: @iappmaker ```hdwallet-provider``` is depricated. try using ```@truffle/hdwallet-provider```

Answer (score 0):

1. I assume you have successfully installed @truffle/hdwallet-provider. If you don't, try this

```
$ npm install @truffle/hdwallet-provider
```

or see https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/blob/develop/packages/hdwallet-provider/README.md#install

2. put your Infura API KEY to `.infura`, and mnemonic to `.secret`. Both are at the same level as `truffle-config.js`.
3. change `truffle-config.js` to something like this

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');

const fs = require('fs');
const infuraKey = fs.readFileSync(".infura").toString().trim();
const mnemonic = fs.readFileSync(".secret").toString().trim();

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
     host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
     port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
     network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    },
    ropsten: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/` + infuraKey),
      network_id: 3,       // Ropsten's id
      gas: 5500000,        // Ropsten has a lower block limit than mainnet
      confirmations: 2,    // # of confs to wait between deployments. (default: 0)
      timeoutBlocks: 200,  // # of blocks before a deployment times out  (minimum/default: 50)
      skipDryRun: true     // Skip dry run before migrations? (default: false for public nets )
    },
  },

  // Set default mocha options here, use special reporters etc.
  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      // version: "0.8.0",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
      settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
       optimizer: {
         enabled: false,
         runs: 200
       },
      }
    }
  },
  db: {
    enabled: false
  }
};
```

4. then you can run like this

```
$ truffle migrate --network ropsten
```

5. remember, **DO NOT** commit the `.infura` and `.secret` to GitHub or any repo.